# Admin Payment Method after an Upgrade 2.2.5

Tags: admin, payment-methods, magento-2.2.5, amazon-payment

**Admin > Configuration > sales > Payment Method** after an upgrade to `2.2.5`,

the page display this form with no `active control`, How to resolve this? (Please see picture below)

---

[image]

---

Thank you in advance.